Cannot sendMessage from background script to itself in an extension?
This is my background script:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("background script received message:");
    console.log(message);

});

chrome.runtime.sendMessage("message from backgorund script");

I cannot see the message("message from background script") in console. But messages from content script can be received without problem.

That is normal. According to documentation: If sending to your extension, the runtime.onMessage event will be fired in every frame of your extension ( except for the sender's frame )
